# Form being submitted despite Required tag in model

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-5

As the question heading says, I am working on an MVC C# application where a user will be submitting data.

As customary , I create a model and mark a few fields as mandatory as necessary. Then if the form is submitted, the submit fails and the mandatory fields are highlighted.

However, for reasons I cannot explain, when I submit the form, the form is submitted but fails due to the model being false. Basically, validation is not occurring on the form.
I have recreated the project and re added files to see if I could find the reason but I had no luck, I even coped a create file from a program with a workinng validation, yet my current program still skips it and thows errors.

Would appreciate if I could get any assistance for this issue im clearly not seeing.

Code Below

BundlesConfig

```
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Content/Gridmvc.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/Gridmvc.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));
        }
    }
}
```

Model 
 **MetaData.cs Class**

```
[MetadataType(typeof(metaStudent))]
    public partial class Studentinfo
    {

        public class metaStudent
        {

            //  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Passport size image is required")]
            [DisplayName("Image")]
            public string image { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required")]
            [DisplayName("First Name")]
            public string firstname { get; set; }
            [DisplayName("Middle Name")]
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Middle Name is required")]
            public string middlename { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is required")]
            [DisplayName("Last Name")]
            public string lastname { get; set; }

            [DisplayName("Village")]
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Village is required")]
 public Nullable<int> village { get; set; }
```

Controller

```
   public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include="studentid,firstname,middlename,lastname,villag")] Studentinfo studentinfo, HttpPostedFileBase stuimage)
        {
            try
            {
                if (stuimage == null)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("image", "Please Upload an Image");
                }

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
```

View

```
@model Edu_StuConsole_App.Models.Studentinfo


<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
            todayBtn: "linked",
            autoclose: true,
            maxDate: "+0D",
            todayHighlight: true,
            orientation: 'top auto',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: "-100:+0"
        });
    });


</script>
   @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Student", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @data_ajax = "false" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    <h4></h4>

                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">


                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.image, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    <input type="file" name="stuimage" id="stuimage" accept="image/*" style=" width: 100%;" onchange="check()" />
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.image)




                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">


                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.firstname, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.firstname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.firstname)
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.middlename, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.middlename, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.middlename)
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.lastname, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.lastname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.lastname)
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.village, "Village", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.DropDownList("village", null, String.Empty, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.village)
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

**Small Potion of Layout page**

```
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge,chrome=1'><![endif]-->
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")


...
   </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where have you included the `jquery` and `jqueryval` bundles?

Comment: Does `village` have the appropriate `public string village { get; set; }`? It's not listed in your code sample.

Comment: You need to check the form before let it submit. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28765716/form-gets-submitted-even-if-the-required-fields-are-left-empty-in-angular-js)[Here]. `form.$invalid` needs to be checked either to disable the submit button or `form.$valid` needs to be passed to the function to decide whether to proceed or not.

Comment: @ObsidianAge yes, i just did not list the entire model but yes it is there

Comment: @StephenMuecke In my Layout page. 
    
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap") button of layout page and 
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") top of my layout

Comment: Then include that info in your question so an answer can be given to solve this.

Comment: @StephenMuecke done.

Comment: @PM. Im confused as to why I would need to do that, normally my validation works by just stating required in my model

Comment: Comment out `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>` in your view (and you also have 2 copies of `jquery-ui.js`). And ignore the incorrect comment by @PM.

Comment: Your scripts are all over the place. You have duplicates, you have them out of order, some in the `<head>` and some in the `<body>`. You need to be consistent. Use bundles everywhere. In your view, render your scripts inside `@section scripts {`

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes, its mostly all over because I was dissecting the application to try and the problem. 
Right now the validation on my text boxes work, but not the one on my image and drop down list

Comment: You do not have a form control for property `image` - your just creating a manual input with a `name` that does not even relate to your model. And what dropdownlist?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146584/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-niana).